# Поиск в таблице БД MS SQL по значению из связанной таблицы C#

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms, sql-server, поиск

Помогите реализовать поиск.
Делаю программку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При выборе "искать по ФИО", в поисковое поле вписывается фамилия и dataGridView Заказ, должны показываться только подходящие записи в бд. Но проблема в том, что в столбце "Клиент" содержится код клиента из таблицы "Клиент"(то есть какая либо цифра), а сама же фамилия уже содержится в таблице "Клиент". Я понимаю, что надо искать фамилию по таблице "Клиент", и если код этой фамилии равен коду клиенту из таблицы "Заказ", то отобразить эту запись. Но не понимаю как это реализовать.

P.S. прошерстил все форумы, но не нашёл подходящих тем. Сорян, если вопрос такой был уже, просто значит не смог найти.

P.P.S. И можно ли это как либо реализовать, через bindingSource.Filter?

Comment: чем пользуешься для доступа к БД? когда select 2-х таблиц - без join не обойтись

Comment: Спасибо, натолкнули на мысль, что-то не подумал о join)